# Q: Lightbox 2 data-title and data-lightbox not show and image is transparent

Tags: lightbox

I've downloaded and added Lightbox 2 to my site, but have a couple of weird things going on. The `data-title` and `data-lightbox` don't show up at all and the lightbox image is transparent as well as the overlay for some reason. I've put the script at the bottom of my page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't given us anything to work with here.  We need source code, examples, etc. so we can see the problem and help you take care of it.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just downloaded the code off the lightbox 2 site - I haven't changed the code at all.  Here's part of the js

Comment: Lightbox.prototype.enable = function() {
    var self = this;
    $('body').on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]', function (event) {
      self.start($(event.currentTarget));
      return false;
    });
  };

Comment: // Support both data-lightbox attribute and rel attribute implementations
    var dataLightboxValue = $link.attr('data-lightbox');
    var $links;

    if (dataLightboxValue) {
      $links = $($link.prop('tagName') + '[data-lightbox="' + dataLightboxValue + '"]');
      for (var i = 0; i < $links.length; i = ++i) {
        addToAlbum($($links[i]));
        if ($links[i] === $link[0]) {
          imageNumber = i;
        }
      }

Comment: } else {
      if ($link.attr('rel') === 'lightbox') {
        // If image is not part of a set
        addToAlbum($link);
      } else {
        // If image is part of a set
        $links = $($link.prop('tagName') + '[rel="' + $link.attr('rel') + '"]');
        for (var j = 0; j < $links.length; j = ++j) {
          addToAlbum($($links[j]));
          if ($links[j] === $link[0]) {
            imageNumber = j;
          }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Regarding the transparent image - I'm not sure which problem that may be...the css is .lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  }

Comment: AND                                                                                                                   .lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: none;
  border-radius: 3px;

  /* Image border */
  border: 4px solid white;
}

.lightbox a img {
  border: none;

}

.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;

  /* Background color behind image.
     This is visible during transitions. */
  background-color: white;
}

Comment: Put your code in your question rather than in multiple comments please. That's the standard way to present a question.